# VB.NET ListView SmallIcon view misaligned due to long text. Need to set fix Label size

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a ListView in SmallIcon view and the issue is when the text is very long it misaligns all the other items.  I want to be able to set them up like Windows Explorer does, 2 or 3 columns with a fixed label size for all and an ellipse at the end of the text if its too long for the label.  I don't need tricks like shorten the text and I've looked all over with no result.  I don't need a class example, I'm looking for something like a SendMessage api call or something similar.  Same goes for the "List" View, I would like to set the label width.  Something like what tilesize does for Tile View.

Currently looks like this

[image: Current Look:]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like I can play with the item positions, will play around with that and see what I can some up with.

Comment: Looks like position doesn't work, even Microsoft's example doesn't work ... will keep looking ...

Comment: I figured out a work around.  Please close.